# How to hack flash game timers?

Tags: flash

I know some games in which games timers are shown in 11:00 time format and in some normally like 100 units of time. I wanted to know how to increase or decrease time in such flash games?
I can't figure anything out after Flash updated to flash player 11 or 12.

Answer (score 1):

If the time is counting up, it's literally impossible because that is server time. Unless the time is counting down, you can't hack it to go faster.
This is for online flash games like I am ninja, that is.

If the flash game isn't online, then just use Cheat Engine.
If it says DLL failed to inject, download "Forced-Injection"
then simply enable the speed hack.
If that STILL doesn't work, use Cheat Engine 32 BIT or 64 bit.